# Is it possible to pick the phone set time format for a wp7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to pick the time format specified in the device (24-hr or 12-hr) to use the same in the application that I develop. Is it possible to do so in WP7?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply use the `ToString` method on a `DateTime` it will automatically use whatever format the user has specified. The problem comes if you want to customize the format slightly. The following code does hours and minutes using 24-hr/12-hr according to the device setting:

```
string modified = CultureInfo
    .CurrentCulture
    .DateTimeFormat
    .LongTimePattern
    .Replace(":ss", "");
string dateFormat = string.Format("{{0}}, {{1:{0}}}", modified);
string formattedTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat);
```

Comment: I would like to know if it is possible for us to detect if the time format set in the phone is 12 hr or 24 hr programatically.

Comment: The only way I can think of to actually "detect" which format is in use would be to actually format a a time such as 1PM as a string and see if it comes out as two characters or 1.